# Using C++, how can I run a python file in Qt Designer?

Tags: python, c++, qt, qt-designer, pyuic

I've finally decided to make the transition from WxPython to QT! I'm using Qt Designer5.9, but I'm having issues placing a new slot. My goal is to press a `button` on the GUI and have a function run that I have written in another python program.

In Qt Designer, I "`go to slot`", select `clicked()` and this appears.

mainwindow.cpp

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{

}
```

Which is exactly what I want, but the wrong language! My python is bad enough let alone anything else. So by running [this tutorial](https://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=first+qt5+app+tutorial&&view=detail&mid=A46E3B63D4A22D57B4ECA46E3B63D4A22D57B4EC&FORM=VRDGAR) I know that if I pass through `ui->textEdit->append(("Hello World"));` I can do something custom, but after converting using **pyuic** to convert to **.py** it's not obvious how it's being implemented. My function is easy to import as shown below, I just need to know where to put it.

```
import myfunction
myfunction()
```

Can anyone give me an example of what needs to be written in C++ in Qt Designer so I can call my python function after .ui conversion??

Comment: why not use PyQt?

Comment: If you want to used embedding python in C++ you can refer this link.  https://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/qq23-pythonqt.html However it's quite complicate you need to have available python libs first.

Comment: This is PyQt5, Qt Designer is the visual implementation of it so you can drag and drop buttons.

Comment: Maybe it's not clear but I am essentially asking how to do it in PyQt.

Comment: you could transfer the origin Qt Designer .ui  file to .py file rather than use the cpp file generated by Qt.`python pyuic.py -o pathto/Pyfile pathto/Uifile`if using pyqt you should have `pyuic`

Comment: If you want a similar behavior to Qt Creator does it for C ++ but for python I recommend using eric IDE https://eric-ide.python-projects.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you need C++, you can do what you want in python. Design your UI in QT Designer. I like to avoid using pyuic, I prefer using the following way, maybe you will find it better. Say your UI file is called something.ui, and you have named your button in QT Designer pushButton_2, then the code in python will be:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic
Ui_somewindow, _ = uic.loadUiType("something.ui") #the path to your UI

class SomeWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_somewindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_somewindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.yourFunction)

   def yourFunction(self):
        #the function you imported or anything you want to happen when the button is clicked.

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = SomeWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is a different workflow than I was expecting but this is the exact answer I was looking for thanks!